# Inquiry on Point Cloud Processing for Robot Navigation Simulation

Tags: python

I am working on a project aimed at utilizing point clouds for creating a simulated environment for robot navigation. The process I am employing is delineated below, and I would greatly appreciate your expertise in verifying the appropriateness and effectiveness of this method for addressing point cloud incompleteness and further utilization in a robotic navigation simulation.

1.Increment the histogram counts for both the xz-plane and yz-plane of the point cloud.

2.Apply a predefined threshold to halt the count increment.
Compute the product (logical AND operation) of the remaining coordinates in the xz-plane and yz-plane.

3.Generate points in the point cloud from the computed coordinate products, thereby forming the ground of the point cloud.

4.Enhance the granularity of the points through voxelization.

5.If the voxels are connected, mesh them together while retaining a rectangular box shape, akin to a Minecraft-like structure.

I am keen on understanding if the steps outlined provide a robust method for processing point cloud data to create a dependable simulation environment for robot navigation. Your feedback on any potential improvements or alternate methodologies would be highly valued.

The above is the code that executed the above.

```py
import math
from collections import defaultdict
from typing import DefaultDict, Dict, List, Tuple

# Third Party Library
import open3d as o3d
from plyfile import PlyData


def read_ply_file(filepath: str) -> List[Tuple[float, float, float]]:
     vertices: List[Tuple[float, float, float]] = []
     plydata = PlyData.read(filepath)
     for vertex in plydata["vertex"]:
         x, y, z = vertex["x"], vertex["y"], vertex["z"]
         vertices.append((x, y, z))
     return vertices


def create_histogram(
     vertices: List[Tuple[float, float, float]], bin_size: float
) -> Tuple[
     DefaultDict[Tuple[int, int], int], DefaultDict[Tuple[int, int], int]
]:
     histogram_xz: DefaultDict[Tuple[int, int], int] = defaultdict(int)
     histogram_yz: DefaultDict[Tuple[int, int], int] = defaultdict(int)
     for x, y, z in vertices:
         binned_x = math.floor(x / bin_size)
         binned_y = math.floor(y / bin_size)
         binned_z = math.floor(z / bin_size)
         histogram_xz[(binned_x, binned_z)] += 1
         histogram_yz[(binned_y, binned_z)] += 1
     return histogram_xz, histogram_yz


def threshold_histogram(
     histogram: Dict[Tuple[int, int], int], threshold: int
) -> Dict[Tuple[int, int], int]:
     return {k: v for k, v in histogram.items() if v > threshold}


def generate_points(
     histogram_xz: Dict[Tuple[int, int], int],
     histogram_yz: Dict[Tuple[int, int], int],
) -> List[Tuple[int, int, int]]:
     new_vertices: List[Tuple[int, int, int]] = []

     for (x, z), count in histogram_xz.items():
         for _ in range(count):
             new_vertices.append((x, 0, z)) # y-coordinate is set to 0

     for (y, z), count in histogram_yz.items():
         for _ in range(count):
             new_vertices.append((0, y, z)) # x-coordinate is set to 0

     return new_vertices


def voxelize_point_cloud(
     pcd: o3d.geometry.PointCloud, voxel_size: float, save_dir: str
) -> o3d.geometry.VoxelGrid:
     # Convert point cloud to voxel grid
     voxel_grid = o3d.geometry.VoxelGrid.create_from_point_cloud(
         pcd, voxel_size=voxel_size
     )
     o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([voxel_grid])
     o3d.io.write_voxel_grid(f"{save_dir}/voxel.ply", voxel_grid)
     # Save voxel grid to new file
     return voxel_grid # Return the voxel grid or perform other operations as desired


def process_point_cloud(
     ply_file_path: str,
     threshold: int,
     bin_size: float,
     voxel_size: int,
     save_dir: str,
) -> None:
     vertices = read_ply_file(ply_file_path)
     histogram_xz, histogram_yz = create_histogram(vertices, bin_size)
     thresholded_histogram_xz = threshold_histogram(histogram_xz, threshold)
     thresholded_histogram_yz = threshold_histogram(histogram_yz, threshold)
     new_vertices = generate_points(
         thresholded_histogram_xz, thresholded_histogram_yz
     )
     pcd = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
     pcd.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(new_vertices)
     o3d.io.write_point_cloud(f"{save_dir}/new_point_cloud.ply", pcd)
     voxelize_point_cloud(pcd, voxel_size, save_dir)
```

Thank you for your time and consideration.

Best Regards